# Plot effects from lme with restricted x range by z variable

Tags: r, plot, effects

I am trying to plot a 3 way interaction effect using the output from lme and the effects package. While I have been able to produce a graph, the graph lines extend the length of the x variable, although each z variable only has a range of actual x data, so I was looking for an option like fullrange=F as seen in ggplot2. There doesn't seem to be a fullrange option with effects or plot, and I have yet to come across an answer on how I might restrict the x axis range BY each variable of z.
Any suggestions on how might plot in a single plot the effects of my lme for each z variable only for the given x ranges for that variable?

```
lme.vol.itx=lme(CortexVol ~ Actual.Age*SexCoded*TannerStage+ICV, random= ~1 | StudyID,      data = data_long_tanner, na.action=na.omit, method="ML")
print(summary(lme.vol.itx)) 
ep=effect(term="Actual.Age:SexCoded:TannerStage", mod=lme.vol.itx, default.levels=5)
plot(ep, multiline=TRUE, rug=F, x.var="Actual.Age", z.var="TannerStage",     colors=c("black", "deepskyblue", "green4", "purple", "red"))


Data
Actual.Age = x variable: range 0 to 6, continuous
5 levels of z variable: range 1:5 in increments of 1
2 levels of SexCoded = 0 boys, 1 girls

Range of Actual.Age by 5 levels of z in boys:
z=1 Ages: 2.07 to 3.24
z=2 Ages: 1.73 to 4.81
z=3 Ages: 2.06 to 6
z=4 Ages: 2.29 to 5.82
z=5 Ages: 3.23 to 6.15

Range of Actual.Age by 5 levels of z in girls:
z=1 Ages: 1 to 1.4
z=2 Ages: 0.14 to 3.9
z=3 Ages: 1.13 to 3.54
z=4 Ages: 1.32 to 5.42
z=5 Ages: 2.27 to 5.91
```